# How to Speed up Ruby Page Object .visible? or exists? Checks

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am using the Page Object Ruby gem to test web pages, and have run into some small performance issues. I have the need to check that elements exist on the current page, but experience long wait times, sometimes in the tens of seconds, with my current method of using .visible? or .exsits?. This performance issue is happening when the element in question does **not** actually exist on the page.

The html is fairly convoluted so providing an example is difficult, but here is the basic format of the table the code should be looking for:

```
<body>
  <div>
  <div>
  <div>
  ...
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href = "#" onclick="return url_here"
        </td>
        <td class= "no wrap">Active<
        <td class= "no wrap">06/15/2016</td>
        <td class= "no wrap">06/15/2016</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <tr>
     </tbody>
    <tfoot>...</tfoot>
  </table>
...
```

I set the element like so:

```
table(:attributes_tbody, :xpath => "//*[@id='Form:agrAttributesTable']/tbody")
```

Then use this code to check whether this table is present on the page:

```
if attributes_tbody_element.visible?
  attributes_tbody_element.each do |row|
    if row[1].text == to_title_case(attribute)
      p 'EXPECTED ATTRIBUTE EXISTS'
    end
  end
end
```

The first if check is what takes the most time. I do realize these methods have a lot to sort through, but I am wondering if there is a way to narrow down what is being searched through to speed up these checks? The page in this case is fairly small and generated using JSF, if that helps.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: An example of the HTML/CSS needed to reproduce the problem might help.

Comment: Providing the whole of the HTML on here would be troublesome, what major parts are you looking for?

Comment: It would be whatever it takes to allow us to reproduce the issue (ie we can run the page/code locally).

Comment: Sadly this is a webpage from work, and so providing the necessary code would most likely not be allowed. Plus i would think the JSF structure would be difficult to replicate. Would there happen to be any general ways to limit what these methods search through? Like say, having it only check inside certain divs, for example.

Comment: Yes, you could write a more specific XPath. I'd first try searching for a table (rather than any element) - `//table[@id='Form:agrAttributesTable']/tbody`. If that doesn't help, you could be more specific about where the table is - eg `//div[@id='some_ancestor']//table[@id='Form:agrAttributesTable']/tbody`

Comment: I will give these suggestions a try shortly, but I feel I should mention this; the performance issue is when the element does not actually exist on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it's related to an implicit wait that you have set on your script(s). Implicit wait will wait the prescribed time until the element appears every time you search for an element. So, if you have a lot of elements that you are looking for or checking visibility, etc. that are missing, you will have a lot of delays. I would suggest you turn off implicit wait and add explicit waits where needed, e.g. `WebDriverWait`.

See the [Selenium docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) for more info on Explicit and Implicit waits.

Comment: This is definitely worth a try but I have one question. How can I be sure that any explicit wait I set is enough time for Selenium to scan the entire page? I'd like it to take one second or less, but is that enough time?

Comment: Selenium will work until it's done. It's single threaded (in general) and walks through the code one line at a time. If you told it to do a search, it's going to complete that search before it moves to the next line of code. The waits are only to wait for a specific event, e.g. an element to become visible, etc. Depending on how much your are scraping the page, 1s per page may not be a reasonable goal.

Comment: So it would appear that selenium is unable to scrape the page quick enough (it takes around 5-6 seconds on average), I'm simply asking too much of selenium!

Comment: You may be able to improve the performance of your scraping further. Did you completely turn off implicit waits? If you will post another question for improving performance of your code, I will try to take a look and offer some advice... if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if and how you resolved your issue, so here goes...

You can define default page and element wait times in Page-Object using 
PageObject.default_page_wait and PageObject.default_element_wait and follow that up with element_wait methods.

There is already a [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394177/changing-default-timeout-of-element-level-waits-in-page-object-gem) for the default waits and a great explanation for element wait methods [here](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Ajax-Calls).

Also, instead of using xpath, the Page-Object "way" would be defining the parent and then the child element as in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098696/accessing-a-nested-element-3-levels-deep-using-page-objects).

Your table would be something like:

```
table(:ur_tbl, :id =>'Form:agrAttributesTable')
ur_tbl.when_present(time_to_wait)
ur_tbl_element[0][1].when_present(time_to_wait)
```

//uses the cell but other elements can be used as well

For your case, you can also set the default element wait high and then revert after your logic to validate the element is complete.

One scenario where you may need slightly extra logic is when the data is already present in the table before the load action is performed. I would assume the app has a pageloader or an overlay element during that time which should be validated.